# Erron using invokeAndWait in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created a Swing GUI which is called from an other Java class file.

constructor of the GUI:

```
public AdviceGUI(AdviceModel model) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("I am called");

    //AdviceGUI.model= model;
    initComponents();

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdviceGUI.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdviceGUI.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdviceGUI.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdviceGUI.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    //check
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new AdviceGUI(model).setVisible(true);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Function Calling the GUI's constructor in the main Java class:

```
public Map<String,ArrayList<String>> queryExpertGUI(AdviceModel model) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
    for(String str : model.orderedQueries) {
        Utils.println("Clause:" + str);
    }

    //Modes file
    //String mode_dir =  cmdArgs.getTrainDirVal()
    System.out.println("sssssssssss"+" "+model.convertModelForBK());

    model.setUserClauses(model.convertModelForBK());
    System.out.println("ssss"+" "+model.userClauses);

    AdviceGUI a = new AdviceGUI(model);
```

Use case is call the GUI in for loop every time the function calling the constructor of the GUI is called and wait until the GUI(Jframe) closes after clicking a button in GUI. To accomplish this I have used the invokeAndWait() in the constructor. But I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1303)
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1296)
at edu.wisc.cs.will.Boosting.UI.AdviceGUI.<init>(AdviceGUI.java:87)
at edu.wisc.cs.will.Boosting.UI.AdviceGUI$1.run(AdviceGUI.java:90)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

New to Java, any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You're messing with the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and you're loosing, if you want to work with Threads inside Swing, either use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) or a [Swing Worker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: @Frakcool Can you please explain it more?

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` are used to transfer execution from a background thread to the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT), where manipulation of the UI elements is allowed.  If you are already on the EDT, you do not need to switch threads.

Comment: @AJNeufeld so i should use the invokeAndWait() in the function calling the constructor of the GUI?

Comment: @vikky2405 you doing something wrong here. You shouldn't call constructor from itself. Simply call `setVisible(true)` without `invokeAndWait` or `new AdviceGUI(model)`

Comment: Don't call `setVisible` from inside the constructor. Always complete initialization before running business logic. This is especially true for multithreaded code such as GUI code. Constructors are for initialization. Only.

Comment: @vikky2405 Don't change your question.  You can edit your question to add missing details, clarify, improve formatting, fix spelling etc.  But changing your question (by fixing your code based on an answer) invalidates the answer; the answer no longer answers the question because the question changed.  Instead, ask a new question if you still have problems.  Rolling back your question edit -- sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have unintentional recursion going on here:

```
public AdviceGUI(AdviceModel model) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
    // java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { public void run() { try {
    new AdviceGUI(model).setVisible(true);
    // } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) { } } } });
}
```

The `AdviceGUI` constructor will attempt to construct another `AdviceGUI` instance, which will create another, which will create another ...

You should revisit who is creating the first `AdviceGUI` instance, and **at that point**, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() { ... } )` to construct and show the UI, and remove the `invokeLater` from the `AdviceGUI` constructor.

Comment: I have made the edits to my code. I am able to access the UI now but still the code does not wait for the GUI to close. The flow goes on and throws a null pointer on a list which should be ideally populated by the GUIs output.

Comment: Probably because you're jumping the gun on business logic from within the constructor,  @vikky 2405.

Comment: You may be looking for a modal `JDialog`, which can block execution from `.setVisible(true);` until the dialog is closed.